Speaking of a fitted bed sheet, would you call it “inside-out” or “upside-down”if you wanted to indicate that the stitches are facing up?
As the title says, while I’m fairly sure about the answer, I am looking for a valid explanation of which term is correct and why.
I believe that the correct term is inside-out because it’s clearly indicating that the wrong side (stitches) are facing out. Whereas a native speaker is arguing that because the item is mostly flat, you would call it “upside-down” to indicate the same direction.
I have a clear memory of Oxford Elementary Dictionary where it had nice pictures to explain these, but it was using a shirt as an example, rather than a bed sheet!
How can I explain the difference between the two terms and indicate which is the correct term to be used?
To be clear, I am talking about a fitted bed sheet rather than a flat bed sheet.

The pillow-case could be inside out, but not the sheet. My socks and shirt could be inside out, but not the towel. Neither the sheet nor the towel have an 'inside'.

@WeatherVane I forgot to clarify that the sheet is a fitted one, so it does have an inside. Does that make any difference?

I think most native speakers, including myself, would say "inside-out."

I would say a flat sheet is "flipped" or "upside down." However, if you're folding the pillow edge over, you might want the sheet upside down so the edge folded over has the correct side up.

inside out means the seams are showing. So the sheet is inside out.

If someone told me that a fitted sheet (or indeed a flat sheet) was upside down, my immediate assumption would be that the sheet needed to be rotated so that the part at the head of the bed moves to become the foot.

I think fitted sheets are capable of being inside-out, upside-down, laterally inverted and existing in another dimension all at once.  Their physics is...different.

@BWFC As anyone who has ever tried neatly folding one is only all too aware.

The 'in' side of the fitted sheet lies hidden against the mattress, the 'out' side is exposed until the flat sheet is placed on top.  When these positions are reversed it is literally inside-out.  To be 'upside-down' the sheet would have to be under the mattress with the fitted corners curled over the top of it. This  makes no sense.

Take fitted sheet, with fitted-corners down, ready to fit on mattress - turn/flip sheet over so bottom is on the top and the fitted-corners pointing/curling-up  - it's now upside-down - you can see the stiches because you can see "inside" the fitted parts, but it's not inside-out as the stiches are clearly still inside.  Now reach inside and pull the corners out so that the fitted-corners now roll downwards - it's now inside-out - the stiches are on the outside.  The direction the stiches face (up/down/left/right) is irrelevant.

To add fuel to the fire: What does 'back-to-front' signify in relation to a fitted sheet?

"Fitted sheet" is really a "border line" term when it comes to deciding whether the device named by this word has an inside and an outside or rather a bottom and a top.
There are two main types of definition;  a fitted sheet is often conceived as a pocket, and according to that idea the term "inside out" is proper (since one could never consider right the idea of  turning their trousers pockets "upside down" (ngram, trousers pockets upside down,trousers pockets inside out,trouser pockets upside down,trouser pockets inside out)). However, the idea that a fitted sheet is essentially a covering also gives rise to the use of the prepositions "over" and "above" in the definitions; along this line of thinking the alternate "upside down" point of view is also quite justifiable.
This points to the conclusion that  neither term can be called definitely illogical and that both are acceptable.
POCKET

(Wikipedia fitted sheet (plural: fitted sheets)
A sheet tailored to form [a] pocket for a mattress with elastic edges that is suitable for a range of mattress sizes. The edge may also contain a drawstring to secure the sheet more firmly and enable use on a wider range of mattress thicknesses.


(ADictionary) fitted sheet A sheet tailored to form a pocket for a mattress […]


(bab.la) fitted sheet noun a fabric sheet with elasticated corners designed to fit tightly over a mattress

COVERING

Collins Dictioanry fitted sheet a sheet with ends that are elasticated and shaped to fit tightly over a mattress


ELL Fitted is the word you are looking for, a fitted sheet is the sheet above the mattress that has extra fabric to extend around the mattress and an elasticized outer edges to fit around the mattress holding it in place.


(STORABLES.COM) Definition of a Fitted Sheet
A fitted sheet, also known as a bottom sheet, is a type of bed sheet designed to fit snugly over a mattress. Unlike a flat sheet, which is a rectangular piece of fabric placed on top of the mattress, a fitted sheet has elasticized corners that allow it to stretch and wrap tightly around the corners of the mattress.


(Oxford Languages) (registration needed for consultation)  fitted sheet
noun: fitted sheet; plural noun: fitted sheets
a fabric sheet with elasticated corners designed to fit tightly over a mattress.


Sorry, but every "fitted sheet" that I have ever seen clearly has an inside and an outside - nothing borderline about it.

@MikeB I agree, they all have a clear inside and outside - but I also agree that they have a clear top and bottom. So just like LPH here, I would accept "upside down" just as much as "inside out"

A fitted sheet is a garment for your bed. Like garments, it can be inside out.

@TinfoilHat If you can call a fitted sheet a garment for your bed you can call a cap a garment for your head (image, usual term: "headgear"), but would we rather say that someone was wearing their cap upside down or inside out? This ngram shows that "outside" is only a little bit more frequent than "underside" when speaking about caps.

We would say he is wearing his cap inside out, not upside down. And I don’t what you’re trying to show with the ngram; there’s pretty well nothing but mushroom caps involved with underside.

@TinfoilHat Here is a case with "upside down" for a beer cap, wich shows a very similar situation: https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Fun_Bachelor_Party_Games/PnWQ6ka1K98C?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22cap+upside+down%22&pg=PT28&printsec=frontcover

That would be a beer bottle cap — and it’s not a garment for a beer bottle.
